# What is the default kafka ack policy for @KafkaListener?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Let's say I have such a listener and no custom kafka configuration:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${my_topic_listen}", autoStartup = "true")
public void listenForMessage(String message) {
    log.info("new message from kafka topic received: {}", message);
    if(message.length() >1000) {
       throw new RuntimeException("TooLongMessage");
    }
    log.info(message is checked);
}
```

1. Will ack be sent before

   log.info("new message from kafka topic received: {}", message);

is called ?

2. if answer for the first question is "No". Will be ack sent even in case of exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will be ack sent even in case of exception ?

It depends on the error handler.

By default, the record causing the exception will be retried up to 9 times before being logged and ack'd. You can configure the retry behavior, and add a custom recover to take some action when retries are exhausted (or use the provided `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`. You can also configure which exceptions are retryable, and which are not.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: I tried to repeat the example you linked and experienced the issue. Created separated topic for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76481597/messagehandlingexception-missing-header-kafka-deliveryattempt-for-method-para

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_consumerposition), the ack will be sent to the broker only after the message is consumed by the consumer.

1. Ack will be sent after the listenForMessage method is completely executed.
2. Since the exception is not related to the failure of working environment, the kafka consumer marks the message as consumed and sends the ACK to the broker.