# MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'kafka_deliveryAttempt' for method parameter type

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka listener with additional header KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "$my_topic}", autoStartup = "true")
public void listenForMessage(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) int delivery) {
    log.info("Message from kafka topic {}", message);
    ...
```

Based on documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#delivery-header

> When using @KafkaListener with the DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper or
> SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper, it can be obtained by adding
> @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) int delivery as a parameter to
> the listener method.

Looks like I've done it.

But second step is not clear for me:

> To enable population of this header, set the container property
> deliveryAttemptHeader to true. It is disabled by default to avoid the
> (small) overhead of looking up the state for each record and adding
> the header.

How can I do it ?

Without second step I see the error:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void ****.listenForMessage(java.lang.String,int)]
Bean [****MessageConsumer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2e2a4bd@3cc101bf]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'kafka_deliveryAttempt' for method parameter type [int], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=.....
```

### Update

I also tried

```
@Bean
public ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> containerCustomizer(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory) {
    ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> custCustomizer = container -> {
        container.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
    };
    factory.setContainerCustomizer(custCustomizer);
    return custCustomizer;
}
```

But it didn't help although I see in debug that this property was set up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So76481597Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So76481597Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so76481597", topics = "so76481597")
    void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) int del) {
        System.out.println(in + ":" + del);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so76481597").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so76481597", "foo");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> containerCustomizer(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory) {

        ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> cust = container -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setDeliveryAttemptHeader(true);
        };
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(cust);
        return cust;
    }

}
```

```
foo:1
```

If you can't figure it out, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I tried to create a separated project and this code works. But in my actual project it doesn't work. I can't find the difference. I tried to change libraries versions but no luck. I have No additional  kafka configuration. I am confused.

Comment: Are you using a custom error handler? The delivery attempt state requires the error handler to implement `DeliveryAttemptAware`. See the `DefaultErrorHandler`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#delivery-header

Comment: No. I don't use custom error handler

Comment: If you can’t reproduce it with a simple example, there is not much I can do to help you. Use a debugger to see what’s going on.